# Flatten XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

***Problem***

Input:

```
<root>
    <node attr="nodeAttr">
        <node attr2="childNodeAttr">
            <node attr3="childChildNodeAttr">
                <item>...</item>
                ...
            </node>
        </node>
    </node> 
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
    <node attr="nodeAttr" attr2="childNodeAttr" attr3="childChildNodeAttr">
        <item>...</item>
        ...
    </node>
</root>
```

Or

```
<root>
    <node>
        <attr>nodeAttr</attr>
        <attr2>childNodeAttr</attr2>
        <attr3>childChildNodeAttr</attr3>
        <item>...</item>
        ...
    </node>
</root>
```

***Attempt***

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/node">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeAttribute" select="@attr" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/node/node">
        <xsl:variable name="nodeAttribute2" select="@attr2" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/node/node/node">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nodeAttribute"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nodeAttribute2"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@attr3"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

***Details***

I'm very new to XSLT and having trouble figuring out how to use it. Clearly my attempt above doesn't really make sense.

I've read several examples but I'm having trouble with the more complicated examples. Are there any other good sites besides W3C and w3school that can help me learn?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You may want to read something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html to better understand XSLT transforms.

Comment: @DavidZemens I was having some trouble pasting my code. I kind of figured that the solution wasn't too difficult for someone who was experienced and was hoping to use that as a jumping off point to research further.

Comment: @JamesBlack thanks for the link I'm reading it now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspire yourself from this sample:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/node">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant-or-self::node/@*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::item" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```